# Lock an arbitrary resource in Python

Tags: python, django, thread-safety

I'm building a payment form in Django, and for obvious reasons I need to make sure that the same payment can't be processed twice (via user clicking twice, for example). I understand how I can create, acquire and release a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object, which would prevent the form from processing two payments at once, but what I want is to just prevent concurrent payments for the same purchase (stored in the database).

I can solve the problem by creating my own db-based Lock system:

```
class LockToken(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def create_for(cls, obj_cls, obj_id):
        bits = (obj_cls._meta.app_label, obj_cls._meta.model_name, obj_id)
        key = '|'.join(map(str, bits))
        return cls.objects.create(key=key)
```

Is there a better way to do this?